# what is the difference between app-deployments and app-root on openshift?

Tags: openshift

I have an app with about 300M. When I git-push it to the openshift gear with 1GB, the quata used is 900M.
That's becuse the git-repo itself is 300M and then there are the folders app-deployment and app-root which seem to contain a complete copy of the repo, too.

That does not make so much sense to me. Twice is fine, but three times? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, the code is in three places.  You can also configure the app-deployments to store more versions that you can switch between if you need to.  You might double-check what all you are storing in your git repo?  Maybe some of it needs to be in the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR instead, such as images & videos?

Comment: thanks for the hint regarding OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. I indeed have some huge files.

Comment: I found out that gears do not share the data dir - when scaling everything but the app-root/data (=OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR) is copied. That might be a problem.

Comment: You might try hosting those files on Amazon S3 or similar then. (depending on how you are using them)